# Intent from Fragment to Activity - Android Java

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I have an activity wherein there is a button to go back to a fragment. I am not getting to know how to do so, even though I searched the web for it.

This is my java code:

```
public void goBackToNavigationSettings(View v) {
    FragmentManager goBackToNavigationSettings = getFragmentManager();
    goBackToNavigationSettings.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.navigation_settings, new 
    Fragment()).commit();
}
```

I even tried the normal `Intent` code but did not work out.

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`

Answer (score 0):

You somewhat lack of understanding what the activity / fragment are about
What I would suggest is to use single activity app and then building navigation via fragments using [this guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/)